# Python error IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, errno, ioerror

is my script

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import os


givenURL = raw_input("Entrer votre liens ")


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

# initialize session
session = requests.Session()

# getting playlist
response = session.get(givenURL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
playlist = soup.find('a', {'data-playlist': True})['data-playlist']
oname = soup.find("title")
oname.text
print oname.text 

# getting list of videos
url = 'http://animedigitalnetwork.fr/index.php?option=com_vodvideo&view=playlist&format=raw'
response = session.post(url, data={
    'playlist': playlist,
    'season': '',
    'order': 'DESC'
}, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
path = os.path.join('Playlist', oname.text)
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    for video in soup.select('div.adn-video'):
        s = 'http://www.animedigitalnetwork.fr' + video.a.get('href')
        f.write(s + '\n')

# Read the file, and break after printing the first line.        
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.rstrip()
        break
```

I get an error with the script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adnplay.py", line 33, in <module>
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'Playlist/Maria, Sorci\xe8re de gr\xe9, pucelle de force ! - VOSTFR'
```

I use this script to retrieve the playlist of the site and I do not see how to fix the script because I had no problem before

and I do not understand the error

i really need your help  !

ty in advance

Comment: Do you have a folder named "Playlist"? If you don't, you need to create one.

Comment: The filepath string in `path` doesn't correspond to an actual valid directory path on your disk. Get the value of `path` and manually try to navigate there.